# Keyguard/Lockscreen Widget Not appearing

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Android v5.0

**Widget XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="250dp" android:minHeight="40dp" android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
android:initialLayout="@layout/trinity_widget" android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/trinity_widget"></appwidget-provider>
```

The widget is perfectly functional on home screen. But it does not appear on lock screen.

I do not know of any code that would force it's appearance.

Thanks. If you need any other code please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 5.0 lollipop remove widget functionality on keyguard instead use notifications a method to get your app to lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

@Ya-Wang is correct. You can integrate the [Adenda](http://adendamedia.com) SDK though to give your app a custom lock screen component.

I'm affiliated with Adenda for full disclosure.